# Eclipse Syntax Coloring Broken For One File

Tags: java, eclipse, wicket, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-neon

There's one Java class I've been working on, and when I came back to work over the weekend and fired up my workspace, the file was suddenly uncolored. The only thing I can think of that could have caused this is that on Friday I was unsuccessfully trying to enable inline JS recognition in a separate file.

Yes, I'm opening it with the Java editor, I made sure of that.

Interestingly, Eclipse is still treating it like a Java file -- autocomplete is working, and hovering over elements still shows the Javadoc, as would be expected. It's just that nothing is colored.

Additionally, every other file in the same package (and the rest of the workspace) is loading up fine, with coloring and autocomplete and everything. It's just this one that is uncolored.

Yep, I've tried cleaning and restarting the workspace multiple times, rechecking file associations, comparing this file's properties to other files, etc... nothing seems to be changing anything.

The only other thing out of place here is Validation. It's working fine for all the other files, but on this class, it's bringing up some weird warnings. For example, the lines...

```
LinkedHashMap<String, CheckBox> boxes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
```

...are showing these warnings:

- `Invalid location of text (,) in tag (<String>).`
- `Invalid character used in text string ( boxes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      List).`

Of course, these warnings don't make sense, and the code compiles fine.

System info:

- Windows 10 x64
- Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 (with EE plugins installed)
- The class in question is a Wicket page
- The project uses Maven, Ant, and Git (with respective Eclipse plugins)

Comment: well who knows:) maybe you can delete the file, recreate it, add a few lines back at a time.

Comment: All the code is colored fine in another file, but once I rename that other file to the right name, the coloring goes away

Comment: so if you rename the class/file name, the coloring is ok? maybe you can live with that solution for now:)

Comment: You're right, that's an acceptable _temporary_ solution, but I'd like to actually solve the underlying problem... but thanks. +1

Comment: A javadoc comment is unclosed; then all becomes hmtl, hence that tag error. Place `*/` somewhere.

Comment: Well, that would make sense, but the only Javadoc comment in the class is definitely closed. And then, that also wouldn't explain the fact that the code works under a different class name.